# After migrating page to other sandbox got error : View state size exceeded

Tags: package, migration, viewstate

I have VF page and a controller class working fine in my dev sandbox. The same functionality i am trying to migrate to completely different company's sandbox. I deployed all components through package. Package is installed successfully but when i try to open the VF page im getting an error :  **Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded. Actual view state size for this page was 196,86KB** 
I dont think there is any problem with code optimization as code is working fine in one sandbox.

Comment: Have you looked at our [existing questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=135kb) regarding this? This is pretty common problem, and the solution is almost always the same: you need to reduce the amount of data you're storing in your controller.

Comment: But the same page is working fine in one sandbox.

Comment: The amount of data you have in the sandbox where it is exceeding limit is probably much, much larger than the data in the sandbox where it's working. Check this post for possible solution / hack -> https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129610/maximum-view-state-size-limit-135kb-exceeded-help-in-resolve.

Comment: There is no much data in sandbox either as it is new sandbox.

Comment: What kind of sandbox is that - a partial one or a full sandbox? Noting that these contain data even if they are new. There is a hack to remove apex:form in the link I posted above. If it suits your situation, you may try that.

Comment: It is partial copy sandbox and i cannot remove apex:form from the code.

Comment: The issue was with the amount of data in one of picklist(Product) on page. there were huge amount of products in the sandbox which was causing viewstate error so had to add one more picklist on product groups to limit the data getting loaded at page load and had groupings on product to resolve this.